# Overriding a method

Tags: java

```
public class Testing extends JDialog {

    public MyClass myClass;

    public Testing() {

    }
}
```

given the above code, is it possible to override a method in myClass in Testing class?

say myClass has a method named computeCode(),  will it be possible for me to override it's implementations in Testing?  sorry it's been a long time since I've coded.

Comment: thanks very much for the comments dudes.  so i guess i do have to make it a subclass... i think i'll just do it this way.  thanks very much again dudes!!!!

Comment: By the way, you should probably go through your previously-asked questions and accept some answers. This will entice more people to help you out in future. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is generally possible (note that as others have correctly mentioned - you'd need to extend it to override the method). Refer to [this sample](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html):

```
public class Animal {
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method in Animal.");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method in Cat.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        Animal myAnimal = myCat;
        myAnimal.testInstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

Not only is it possible, but it is a key feature in polymorphism an code reusability.

Note, however, that `MyClass.computeCode` might be `final` - in this case, it cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

You override methods of classes that you extend. Therefore, in your example your `Testing` class could override the various existing methods of `JDialog`. If you wanted to override `computeCode()` from `MyClass` (assuming it's not `final`), you should make `Testing` extend `MyClass`.

```
public class Testing extends MyClass
{ 
    @Override
    public int computeCode()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to override a method from MyClass then your testing class must extend that. for overriding  a method one must complete IS-A relationship whereas your code comes under HAS-A relationship.

Comment: More in Entity Relationship language too technical to understand :).

Answer (score 1):

You can override a class's method only in a *subclass* (a class that `extends` the class whose method you want to override).  However, given your skeletal code, you *can* (within `Testing`) have a nested class that `extends MyClass` and force an instance of *that* nested class into the `myClass` instance variable... so, the answer must be "yes".

Whether that's the best choice (as opposed to using interfaces, rather than subclassing concrete classes, and relying on Dependency Injection to get the implementations most suited for your testing), that's a different question (and my answer would be, unless you're testing legacy code that you can't seriously refactor until it's well test-covered... then, probably not;-).

Answer (score 1):

See, if you want to override method from `MyClass` then you need to extend it.
As per your code, it seems you want to make a wrapper wround `MyClass`.

Wrapper means, calling implemented class method will call method of `MyClass`.

I am just clearing how wrapping works as below.

```
public class Testing extends JDialog {

    public MyClass myClass;

    public Testing() {

    }

    public void someMethod() {
       //Add some more logic you want...
      ...
      ..
       myClass.computeCode();

    }

}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the question is confused and lost.

Here are some key points:

- You can't `@Override` something that you didn't inherit to begin with
- You can't `@Override` something that is `final`

Here's a small example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class OverrideExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
        ) {
            @Override public String toString() {
                return "I'm a list and here are my things : " + super.toString();
            }
        };
        System.out.println(list);
        // prints "I'm a list and here are my things : [a, b, c]"
    }
}
```

Here, we have an anonymous class that `@Override` the `toString()` method inherited from [`java.util.ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Note that here, it's not `class OverrideExample` that overrides the `ArrayList.toString()`; it's the anonymous class that (implicitly) `extends ArrayList` that does.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are valid. But, if you want to extend JDialog but still if you want to override a method of another class it is possible through interfaces. Interfaces won't have method definitions but will have method declarations. More about interfaces, you can read at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

In your case, you can make use of interface like this

```
public interface MyInterface{
     public void myMethod();
}
public class Testing extends javax.swing.JDialog implements MyIterface{
     public void myMethod(){
          // code for your method
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Testing class has already inherited JDialog, there is no way let it inherit MyClass again unless to implement an interface. What you can do is to use some design pattern. However this is not overriding, since there is no inheritance. The [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) is the one you need. Again you are losing the flexibility of polymorphism.

```
public class Testing extends JDialog {

 MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

 public Testing() {

 }

 public void methodA(){
     myClass.methodA();
 }

}

 class MyClass {
     public void methodA(){}
 }
```